# jquery select list option focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectlist

I am trying to do a month year drop down that takes the HTML and removes previous months if the current year is selected. All works ok but it always sets the month option focus to the last one in the object, have tried focus, selected with no joy.

http://jsfiddle.net/FneGp/

```
var selectList = $("select#months");
    var selectListOptions = $("select#months option");

    var d = new Date(),
        n = d.getMonth(),
        y = d.getFullYear();
    $("select#years").on("change", function (){
        if ($(this).val() == y) {
            $("select#months").children("option").each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() <= n) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });

        }
        else {
            selectListOptions.appendTo(selectList);
        }
    });
```

I have set up a fiddle to show the problem.

Any help gratefully appreciated

Thanks in advance

Richard

Comment: I can't really see what the error is...and shouldn't the year drop down come before the month?

Comment: no error, its just if you change the year to anything but 2014 + it sets the focus to the last option in the month list, i.e. December

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple solution I would suggest is to change the select as mentioned below

```
<select id="months">       
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
     <option selected="selected">Month</option>
</select>
```

because when appending the last option is getting selected by jQuery.

**EDIT:**

Change your else statement as below

```
else {
            selectListOptions.appendTo(selectList);
            $('#months option:contains("Month")').prop('selected', true);
        }
```

Comment: thanks, sadly that's not an option using MVC and its quite strict

Comment: @user989952 Its Ok, lets try to set the option "month" after appending..  Does this sense?

Comment: @user989952 I forget to mention this, avoid using element before an ID (example: `$("select#months")`).  ID is unique, so you can mention it as  **$("#months")** or **$("#years")**